# Variable initialize - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have no knowledge of Java but trying to build a basic app.

The guide says:

> " Please also note that KontaktSDK must be initialized before first
>   usage, but there is no mandatory to do it in Application class."

Code of app:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Application;

public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        KontaktSDK.initialize(this);
    }
}
```

build.gradle dependencies (synced with no errors):

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.kontaktio.sdk:kontakt-sdk:2.1.2'


}
```

Error:

> Error:(15, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable KontaktSDK

I know that for coders and professionals it is simple, but for a newbie is a no-go. Could someone please advice?

Comment: you add the lib on gradle?

Comment: yes. library is in the gradle and gradle is synced

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your **build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.kontakt.sdk.android:kontakt.io-android-sdk:2.1.0'
}
```

[Official Site](http://developer.kontakt.io/android-sdk/2.1.0/quickstart/)

Comment: following exactly this "guide"/"quick start" and dependency is present in build.gradle (Module: app) (gradle synced without errors)

Answer (score 0):

when you use this line

```
KontaktSDK.initialize(this);
```

basically, this line means KontactsDK attach with your app context 
 When use in Application class. It is run when your app starts that means you can use the SDK anywhere in the app because you initialize it when your app starts. But it is not mandatory to initialize when the app starts you can initialize it whenever you required using the SDK, for example, you just need to use this SDK for a specific condition then there is no use to attach the SDK with your app context. I recommend you if your app heavily uses this SDK then use at Application level otherwise you can initialize it whenever required. Thanks, This info will help you

Comment: So do you mean that the "error" is fine and I should just continue with the app? Sorry.. just haven't get used to "errors" in dev. Warnings -> fine, errors - not really

Comment: there is no error if you initialize it before Use it. you just required initializing the SDK before using it. we use this at application level because it confirms that SDK is Initialize when the app starts.